# NodeJs - callback is not defined - How do I use async for password hashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm fairly new to nodeJS, and I've been tasked with creating a sample registration page, and with it, my attempts at encrypting the user's password.

Here's what I came up with, used by simply passing the user's password:

```
function hashPassword(password) {
  var salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64')
  var iterations = 1000;
  var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, 512, 'sha512');
  return {
    salt: salt,
    hash: hash.toString('base64'),
    iterations: iterations
  };
}
```

Now, I heard that it's best practice to use async on functions that may take awhile, but unfortunately I'm rather new to async on JS.

Here's what I came up with through google searches ([specifically, here](https://gist.github.com/skeggse/52672ddee97c8efec269)), but I neither understand it completely nor could I get it to work. Keeps saying `ReferenceError: callback is not defined`:

```
function hashPassword(password, callback) {
  var saltBytes = 128;
  var iterations = 1000;
  var hashBytes = 512
  crypto.randomBytes(saltBytes, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, hashBytes, 'sha512', (err, hash) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      var combined = new Buffer(hash.length + salt.length + 8);
      combined.writeUInt32BE(salt.length, 0, true);
      combined.writeUInt32BE(iterations, 4, true);

      salt.copy(combined, 8);
      hash.copy(combined, salt.length + 8);
      callback(null, combined);
    });
  });
}
```

As far as my limited knowledge of async goes, it's in the callback function I'm supposed to do whatever else is required (in my case, save to DB).

What did I do wrong, or what am I not getting?

Comment: Well, how did you call your `hashPassword` function, did you pass in a callback?

Comment: *"Now, I heard that it's best practice to use async on functions that may take awhile"* Only if the reason they take a while is that they're waiting on something else (like an I/O event). If they take a while because they're doing work in the JavaScript code, making the function `async` won't help at all. In your case, **yes**, using `pbkdf2` instead of `pbkdf2Sync` would be best practice, because `crypto` offloads the heavy lifting from the JavaScript thread.

Comment: *"Keeps saying `ReferenceError: callback is not defined`"* It clearly **is** defined in the code you're using. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling your function like this ?

```
hashPassword('password here', function (error, combined) {
  if(error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // do something with combined
  }
});
```

I think the error is because you are not sending the callback function as second parameter when you call hashPassword function

[Check this gist](https://gist.github.com/andritogv/816a09b48c21ba1fe92f48c5566c7c05)

Comment: That would result in a different error message (specifically: `TypeError: callback is not a function`). The error message quoted would only be caused by trying to use the identifier `callback` without defining it. But it's defined in the code presented, so for now the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just tested it
[link](https://gist.github.com/andritogv/816a09b48c21ba1fe92f48c5566c7c05)
and result in console was
<Buffer 00 00 00 80 00 00 03 e8 77 5f 30 5f d3 2b 70 84 16 de f6 56 77 7c 33 c8 e9 3d bd 56 a1 2c 1a b9 db 6e 35 0b ad e6 c4 72 94 57 cd c7 87 fa f0 d3 a8 bd ... >
I don't think I deserve your downvote ...

Comment: You don't know who downvoted; you only know who commented. They are *often* not the same people. Regardless, comments on votes are always unuseful.

Comment: Regarding the OP's issue: Please read the comment again, it was quite clear about how this clearly isn't the answer to this question, and indeed about why this question cannot currently be answered.